# Button with a CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms, button, checkbox

We have a requirement to create a button with a `CheckBox` embedded in it.

After trying various option, we found an option of having a `CheckBox` with an appearance of `Button` but that does not suffice as we need to have an event being fired when the `Button` is being clicked but `CheckBox.Checked` state will be used for other modifications.

Can someone guide me on how to proceed with this task?

Comment: Do you need your checkbox to be inside your button?

Comment: How would the UX for this, particularly w.r.t the interaction between them, be consistent with a) checkboxes elsewhere and b) push buttons elsewhere?

Comment: You could also consider using a split button with drop down menu, which would be able to support multiple options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to you can do something like this:

```
checkBox1.Parent = button1;     // make it large enough
checkBox1.Location = new Point(5, (button1.Height - checkBox1.Height) /2 + 1) ;
checkBox1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

[image]

Make sure to set `Texts` and alignments for both to prevent clashes. Also make sure to test if they act as intended..!

You can place the `Button` wherever you want, align it to the right or clear its `Text`..

Of course you can wrap it in a class, if you need it repeatedly..